# webauthn usernameless on android chrome

Tags: webauthn

I want to implement a usernameless authentication using resident keys (client-side discoverable credentials) in WebAuthn. This means, I want to use Resident Credentials, so I would not need to first identify the user. [According to the specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/), I can use `requireResidentKey` for this.

So first, I am registering for a new resident credential:

```js
const randomStringFromServer = 'CHALLENGE';
const publicKeyCredentialCreationOptions = {
    challenge: Uint8Array.from(
        randomStringFromServer, c => c.charCodeAt(0)),
    rp: {
        name: "Test App",
        id: window.location.hostname,
    },
    user: {
        id: Uint8Array.from(
            "UZSL85T9AFC", c => c.charCodeAt(0)),
        name: "asdfassadf@stackoverflow.com",
        displayName: "erdos",
    },
    pubKeyCredParams: [{alg: -7, type: "public-key"}],
    authenticatorSelection: {
        authenticatorAttachment: "cross-platform",
        residentKey: 'required',
    },
    requireResidentKey: true,
    timeout: 60000,
    attestation: "direct"
};

const credential = await navigator.credentials.create({
    publicKey: publicKeyCredentialCreationOptions
});
```

This triggers the webauthn window. When I select my Android device (Chrome version 105.0.5195.136), the notification is shown on the phone, but tapping on that gives the following screen:

```
Something went wrong.

The verification method isn't available for this
device. Pick a different option on your other device.
```

What am I missing here, is it possible to implement usernameless flow on Android Chrome?  Are other mobile browsers with better support?

Comment: I'm suprised microsoft is the only company who's done a proper production release of resident keys (with yubikey). Is your question for a business feature, or for research purposes?

Answer (score 2):

Android does not yet support discoverable credentials.

Answer (score 1):

We hope to have discoverable credential support on Android soon, but it's not currently enabled. If you sign up for the [Play Services beta](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/beta-program) then you'll get it as soon as its available.

For development purposes in the interim, an iOS 16 device should work.

Comment: This will now work. See https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/10/bringing-passkeys-to-android-and-chrome.html